# EF 4.1 - Can't Associate One Entity with another Existing Entity (Nullable FK)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, poco

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 (database first, e.g "old school"), and i'm using POCOs in an ASP.NET MVC 3 web app.

I've got a 1 - 0..1 relationship between `Foo` and `Bar`, backed by a **nullable int** on the `Foo` table.

My POCO's look like this:

```
public class Foo
{
   public Bar Bar { get; set; 
}

public class Bar
{
   public int BarId { get;set; }
}
```

Now, i have a `Foo` which already exists in the system, but `BarId` is null.

Now i'm trying to associate that `Foo` with an existing `Bar`.

This is the code i've got:

```
var existingBar = _repo.GetBar(2);
var existingFoo = _repo.GetFoo(1);
existingFoo.Bar = existingBar;
```

But behind the scenes, EF is adding a **new** `Bar`. Why?

I also tried this:

```
existingFoo.Bar = new Bar { BarId = 2 };
```

E.g the "stub technique", but results in EF complaining about empty columns (because again, it's trying to create a "new" Bar).

I'm sure i've done this before - i just hope the solution i ended up going with wasn't "use a SP".

As i mentioned - i'm using POCO's, so i don't have direct access to the `DbContext` or `ObjectContext` from my controller.

Any advice?

Comment: Do you need "BarId" in your Foo class?

Comment: @Matthew - i do, as in the question..unless you mean something else?

Comment: @Matthew - actually i **dont** have it in my Foo class. Dont need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that's because

> DbContext API and its DbChangeTracker doesn't provide a way to change a state of Independent association (we must convert DbContext back to ObjectContext and change the state in ObjectStateManager).

The above was quoted from [Ladislav Mrnkva's blog post](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/05/foreign-key-vs-independent-associations-in-ef-4/). Try to define the `BarId` property in your `Foo` class and see if it causes the context to work properly.

Comment: Yup, adding `BarId` to the model and simply setting that property to the value did the trick. Thanks!